# us11541217 - Tattooing Apparatus

Tags: assignee, commercial-use

I'm very curious if the technology from the device described in patent [us11541217](https://patents.google.com/patent/US11541217B2) exists in any commercial device, or has yet been built? I cannot find any contact information for the inventors, nor do my searches return anything near what the documentation describes. I'm also curious to know which drive system the inventors favor - voice coil or linear (solenoid?) drive.

Any information on the development of this device or one similar would be greatly appreciated, this tech is a massive leap forward for the craft.

Comment: I edited the tags listed. Tags are to make searching for this question more relevant. Tags specific to this patent like an inventor's name only don't really help that.

Answer (score 1):

If you click on the "USPTO Patent Center" link you'll get to a [page](https://patentcenter.uspto.gov/applications/16763381) which lists a "Address and Attorney/Agent Information" tab. From that you can get the law firm that prosecuted the patent. They should be able to direct you to the inventors and assignee. Here is the firm for you:

**75436 - MORSE, BARNES-BROWN & PENDLETON, P.C.**

ATTN: Patent Group Director
CityPoint
480 Totten Pond Road, 4th Floor
WALTHAM, MA 02451
UNITED STATES

The patent lists Sean Detwiler as the attorney and he is listed in Patent Center with the following phone number.

DETWEILER, SEAN
(781) 622-5930

From the same page you can click the "Assignments" tab and get the address of the assignee which owns the patent.

WIT INNOVATION APS
KOBENHAVNSVEJ 26E
ROSKILDE, DENMARK 4000

Doing a bit of googling I found [this page](https://dk.kompass.com/en/c/wit-innovation-aps/dkcom191054/) with information about WIT Innovation APS. One of the inventors is listed as the CEO.